# When I try to call one procedure inside another procedure I got this sql error "no function with name 'PROC_DISPLAY_FIRSTNAME' exists in this scope "

Tags: sql

I change my executable part as,

```
    BEGIN
      proc_ref_value(orders_id);
      proc_display_firstname(custId);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(orders_id||' '||status||'  '||re_value||' '||cust_last_name );
    END;
```

When I run It, I got output without customer full name.
     Statement processed.

> 10101  completed  0 
>  10102  cancelled  0 
>  10103  completed  0
>   
>  10104  completed  0 
>  10105  refunded  740

But I want to get customer full name from first procedure.

Comment: Hi @OshadeeKaushalya, this is a big mess. Does your 'PROC_DISPLAY_FIRSTNAME' work ok when you run it ? Please check your question again because this code is not ok ... Cheers!

Comment: Your procedure code needs to occur before the main begin block in order for the begin block to see it. But it seems like your procedures are unnecessary, and that you just need to add a cursor for each instead.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: I used live Oracle pl/sql server

Answer (score 0):

This might be starting point based on what it seems you're trying to do with your code. You don't need procedures within your anonymous block, just cursors. Adjust variable types as you need.

```
DECLARE
    orders_id CHAR(5);
    status VARCHAR(10);
    re_value   NUMBER;   
    custId customer.customer_id%TYPE;
    or_status orders.order_status%TYPE;
    total orders.total_order%TYPE;
    v_order_id orders.order_id%TYPE;
    ref_value   NUMBER;
    customer_name varchar2(20);

     CURSOR c1 IS 
     SELECT INITCAP(CONCAT(CONCAT(cust_first_name,' '),cust_last_name)) as cust_name
     FROM customer 
     WHERE customer_id = cust_id;



    CURSOR c2 IS 
    SELECT order_id
           , order_status
           , total_order
           , CASE WHEN   order_status='refunded' THEN total_order*0.25
                  WHEN   order_status='completed' THEN  total_order* 0
                  WHEN   order_status='cancelled' THEN total_order*0
             END order_value
    FROM orders
    where order_id = v_order_id;

BEGIN
  v_order_id := 1; -- your value here

  for x in c2 loop
    or_status := x.order_status;
    total := x.total_order; 
    ref_value := x.order_value;

    for y in c1 loop
      customer_name := y.cust_name;
    end loop;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_order_id||' '||or_status||'  '||ref_value||' '||customer_name);
  end loop;

END;
```

Comment: Sir how do I then get result that I want? It shows "statement Statement processed." only

Comment: There's a dbms_output.put_line which will write to output buffer. Your question doesn't include what format you want your output to look like or what you wish to do with it.

Comment: This is my question sir,                                                                               "Create a procedure which finds the refunded value for each of the orders. For refunded orders, refunded value is 25% of the total order value. For all the orders with any other 
status (completed/cancelled), refunded value should be shown as zero (no refunded value is calculated). The procedure should finally display only the order id, customer’s full name, order status and the refunded value for all the orders.

Comment: I would suggest you join the customer and order tables. Your logic to determine order value will work. But you need to aggregate all the orders for each customer. You can do that one of two ways, either via a group by clause, or by looping through and adding the value to a variable. The dbms_output.put_line will display as requested, but you may need to enable output if using SQL Developer.